# xsl to list files in a directory that starts with MyFile

Tags: xslt, saxon

I have a requirement to process all xml files in a directory that starts with MyFile.
I am using the below xsl:

<xsl:for-each select="collection('../output/${devid}/?select=MyFile*')">

This is failing with invalid relative uri error. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Which version of XSLT are you using?

Comment: Which XSLT processor? What is the dollar sign doing in the URI?

Comment: I am using xsl 2.0. Dollar sign is the param name I am taking.

Comment: When I am using this its working: <xsl:for-each select="collection('../output/${devid}/?select=*.xml')">. But the problem is I want to process only those files that starts with MyFile.

Comment: Which XSLT processor?

Comment: I am using saxon processor

Comment: Is that Saxon run from the command line? See whether the `-t` option gives you more error details. Or do you get a more precise error as to how the URI looks that Saxon rejects?

Comment: If that is a recent version of Saxon that also supports `uri-collection` you might want to see what `<xsl:value-of select="collection('../output/${devid}/?select=MyFile*')"/>` outputs, whether it shows any error as well or the output shows anything not working as a URI.

Comment: Still not sure, however, I understand at what place the `${devid}` is supposed to relate to a parameter as that is certainly not XSLT/XPath syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If `devid` is the name of a stylesheet parameter, then the way you would substitute this into a collection URI is

```
<xsl:for-each select="collection('../output/' || $devid || '/?select=MyFile*')">
```

Alternatively you could do

```
<xsl:variable name="uri">../output/{$devid}/?select=MyFile*</xsl:variable>
<xsl:for-each select="collection($uri)">
```

provided that expand-text is set to "true".